# Unir dos tablas en PHP, mysql

Tags: php, mysql

tengo un problema en PHP. Quiero unir, 4 tablas que tengo para mostrarla como si fuera una sola. No quiero combinar ninguna fila con la otra. He probado con JOIN pero no me funciona.

Lo que necesito es lo siguiente

Tengo estas tablas

tabla 1:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla 2:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven, las tablas tienen los mismos nombres en las columnas. Yo quiero hacer una consulta en PHP donde las dos tablas se muestren como si fueran una sola pero las filas no se unan.

Quiero que quede algo así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He buscado información sobre esto pero en toda siempre usan metodos que unen las filas con la misma id, yo no quiero unir las filas con la misma id. No quiero que ninguna fila se una a otra. No sé si me doy a entender, supongo que en la consulta también se deberían reasignar las ids para que no se dupliquen.

Agradezco su ayuda y pronta respuesta por favor, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para unir varias consultas que tienen los mismos campos (o sea, el mismo nombre y tipo de datos para cada campo) podés utilizar el operador UNION (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html)
Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT campo1, campo2
FROM tabla1
UNION
SELECT campo1, campo2
FROM tabla2
```

Saludos.